# Android - What's the best way to store image to SQLite?

Tags: android, image, sqlite

I am developing an offline application and I'm not getting any picture from user's gallery.
But I want to display the images to the users that I inserted manually.

The only solution I can think of is to put those images into `drawable`, then save it to the sqlite database (which I not sure how). Can this be done?

Thank you.

Comment: You can't (easily) add files to the drawable folder.  You have to save them to your app's folder in the SD card which you can create.  You may also want to look in to content providers to increase functionality. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html

Comment: I see. What if the application is online app?

Comment: If you're downloading the images to the device, it's the same.  If you're just displaying a page, then you may want to look into WebView.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to store the images in the drawable folders, you can store a reference to them in your database. Just store a string like `com.example.yourapp:drawable/imagefilename` and use this to display the image, where `yourString` contains the string from the database..

```
int imageResource = this.getResources().getIdentifier(yourString, null, null);
yourimageview.setImageResource(imageResource);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use insert blob for this

```
    public void insertImg(int id , Bitmap img ) {   


    byte[] data = getBitmapAsByteArray(img); // this is a function

    insertStatement_logo.bindLong(1, id);       
    insertStatement_logo.bindBlob(2, data);

    insertStatement_logo.executeInsert();
    insertStatement_logo.clearBindings() ;

}

 public static byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);       
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```